# Laravel sail (docker) bash alias not remembering

Tags: laravel, bash, docker

I've created a new Laravel application using docker and Laravel Sail. I've used Ubuntu on my Windows 11 computer to store my application using sail. Everything works as intended and I can access my application.

The problem I'm experiencing is that every time I need to run Laravel Sail commands I need to type in the full path: `./vendor/bin/sail (command)`. I know the way to add a bash alias is the following:

```sh
alias sail='[ -f sail ] && bash sail || bash vendor/bin/sail'
```

The issue is that every time I open up Ubuntu using my Windows terminal, or reset my computer, this alias is gone. I'll have to re-apply the command into the terminal to use the alias again, until the next computer refresh.

How can I make sure this bash alias sticks, instead of having to type this out every single time I have to restart my computer?

Comment: This is not specific to docker. *All* aliases need to be sourced into a new copy of bash when it starts, under all circumstances.

Comment: (Also, it's a question that would be better suited to [unix.se] rather than Stack Overflow, being more a question about how to configure your shell as a user than a question about writing software).

Comment: That said, this code won't handle arguments correctly: it'll only pass them through in the `bash vendor/bin/sail` case and not in the `bash sail` case, because aliases are just prefix expansion, so all arguments go only at the very end of the alias.

Comment: _Also_, if a `sail` file exists in the current directory but `bash sail` fails, it'll then try to run `bash vendor/bin/sail`! (That's because `a && b || c` is **not identical to** `if a; then b; else c; fi`).

Comment: The better way to fix both those is _not to use an alias at all_, but instead to use a function. In the same place you configure the alias, you can write `sail() { if test -f sail; then bash sail "$@"; else bash vendor/bin/sail "$@"; fi; }` -- note that if you already configured a `sail` alias in your active shell, you'll need to `unalias sail` before defining the function.

Answer (score 12):

You can add alias depending on the terminal you're using, If you're using `zsh` or `bash`

If zsh then run

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

and then add alias - `alias sail='[ -f sail ] && bash sail || bash vendor/bin/sail'`

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

if you are using `bash` run in your terminal

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and then add alias - `alias sail='[ -f sail ] && bash sail || bash vendor/bin/sail'`,

```
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: This appears to work fine but for some reason the colors from the windows wsl terminal seem to dissapear? Little odd...

Comment: @Florian I have no idea about the windows wsl terminal sorry. I only tried it on MacOS

Comment: Ah nvm on windows with wsl you have to add this line to bashrc instead of bash_profile and I was using echo with a single > instead of >>

Answer (score 1):

Add alias sail='bash vendor/bin/sail' in your .bashrc in your home directory if you are using ubuntu dont know about windows